# Views global counter IF condition is not working?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

Please can anybody solve my problem. its in drupal 7 views, i dont know why the if condition is not getting satisfied ( if($mycount == 1) ) in the following code.

```
foreach ($fields as $id => $field){
    if($field->class == "counter")
    {
        $mycount = $field->content;
        echo $mycount;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    if($field->class == "field-logo")
    {
        var_dump($mycount);  // output 
        echo "<br>";
        if($mycount == 1)   // but here 1 == 1 for the first time. see the output.
        {
            echo "worked";  // its not coming here...
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
string(36) "1"
2
string(36) "2"
3
string(36) "3"
4
string(36) "4"
5
string(36) "5"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is dumped string size - **string(36)** - which suggests `$mycount` content isn't one character but 36 (number "1" and 35 garbage chars). You should try this:

```
$mycount = trim($field->content);

echo '<pre>as string: ' . var_export($mycount, true)
    . ', is_numeric: ' . var_export(is_numeric($mycount), true)
    . ', as integer: ' . var_export((int) $mycount, true) . '</pre><br />';
```

You should see something like this on output:

```
as string: '1', is_numeric: true, as integer: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Views wrapped your field value in some HTML, so your real output might be `<span class="field-content">1</span>`, but in browser you only see "1".

In order to avoid getting the result wrapped in HTML you need to change "View result counter" field style settings to "Customize field HTML" and set "- None -" as drop down value.

Now `$field->content` will return the value without any HTML and `$mycount == 1` in your if statement will be working fine.